# Can I add 'id' column as fillable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I want ad 'id' in user table. The user table is pure from laravel it self. In User.php model there is these syntax

```
protected $fillable = ['name','email',password']
```

Can I add 'id' column at $fillable syntax?.

And can I fill 'id' column without add the column name to $fillable array?

Comment: Making Primary key as fillable is not recommended because it's the value that defines index or unique identity

Comment: If you have another primary key yes you can.

Comment: is your `users` table don't have `id` column ?

Comment: It has `id` column. My purpose is to make unique number as `id` value

Comment: Yes, you can make it fillable and you can change it without making it fillable. Why do you want to make it fillable though? Can you explain your situation?

Comment: if you want it to be fillable, just remove the id as auto increment in table and manually enter id in the table.

Comment: I ever add birthday column and change the adduser controller to fill birthday value without add the column name in $fillable. When I test the app to sign up I get an error. I add the birthday input at the sign up form

Comment: @jitheshjose I want unique number not static number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this question. Maybe I am not getting this right, but I see you repeating one comment in different forms:

> My purpose is to make unique number as id value

This is what an "autoincrement" primary index does for you by default. It is unique because well it's defined as primary and it is autoincremented so you get a single numeric value assigned with one row in the table.

### Suggestion 1

Not sure why would you want to make your life hard by reimplementing something yourself which already has been implemented for you.

When you define a table migration using artisan command with --create paramter, Laravel generates a table migration with the following line in it:

`$table->increments('id');`

which means it makes a column of name 'id' in your table which is PRIMARY and AUTOINCREMENTED for you.

### Suggestion 2

However, if you really want to do it yourself. Sure you can.

The `fillable` array is only there for 'mass assignment'. So if you want to insert the `id` while inserting other values in the table, for example like this:

```
$request['id'] = 123; //my unique number
User::create($request->all());
```

Where $request is obviously an instance of Request facade. Then YES, you need to put the id inside the fillable array.

### Suggestion 3

However, if you just want to change the id separately for an existing model, you could do that even without putting it in `fillable` array, for example:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
$user->id = 123; // my unique number
$user->save();
```

*I hope it helps*